# SQL: Improving the string split

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a set of code that takes a string value, split it, and pass it to a table. The code works, but it runs slow. Any suggestion to modify the code and make it run faster would be greatly appreciated.

```
DECLARE @StrPropertyIDs VARCHAR(1000)

SET @StrPropertyIDs = '419,429,459'

DECLARE @TblPropertyID TABLE
(
property_id varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @TblPropertyID(property_id)

select x.Item
from dbo.SplitString(@StrPropertyIDs, ',') x

select *
from vw_nfpa_firstArv_RPT
where property_use IN
(
SELECT property_id
FROM @TblPropertyID
)
```

Comment: You forgot to include the definition for `dbo.SplitString`. Also, why insert split values into a table variable, and no do `JOIN dbo.SplitString(@StrPropertyIDs, ',') SS ON SS.Item = RPT.property_use`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best long term strategy here would be to move away from CSV data in your SQL tables if at all possible.  As a quick fix here, we could try creating the table variable with an index on `property_id`:

```
DECLARE @TblPropertyID TABLE (
    property_id varchar(100) INDEX idx CLUSTERED
);
```

This would make the `WHERE IN` clause of your query faster, though we could try rewriting it using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM vw_nfpa_firstArv_RPT t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TblPropertyID t2
              WHERE t2.property_id = t1.property_use);
```

Note that this would only work on SQL Server 2014 or later.

Comment: I think that creating an index on a table variable is not allowed on the SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Yes, but this means that you need to change something else to get the result you want.